# Paperclip ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I keep getting this error. Everything looks right to me but I am not sure why the error is showing up

[image: Error]

This is my code. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

[image: Code]

Comment: Is there an `image` attribute in your Listing model?

Comment: can you show us your `Listing` model.

Comment: I will but I am not sure what the listing model is? If you would be able to expound that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run paperclip generator if you didn't do that:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations

```
rails generate paperclip listing image
```

that will create a migration to add all necessary attributes to listing table for you to save the file information. Then you make sure you tell to **Listing** model that **it has an attached file**:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

This will add a virtual attribute called image to your model, the one you are missing. After the steps above you should be able to upload image.